# How to link cloud database with phonegap app?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, phonegap

So I am trying to write a mobile app using phonegap that will manage inventory. I need it to communicate with a cloud-based SQL database. I would like to know how to read from and write to an SQL database that is in the cloud and the basics of how I might go about setting this up within phonegap. I read a little bit about it before and I think I understand the concept, but I just don't know how to write the code and I would love to learn. So far (from reading other stackoverflow threads) here's what I have:

*Update*: I made a Google Cloud SQL database and installed gcloud sdk and google cloud sdk proxy on my machine. Not sure how this will work when building the app, though. Also, I still don't know how to get the ajax to work to connect to the proxy.

I have a snippet of code that is supposed to be an ajax request that calls a php file (but it says "val" is undefined and I don't know what "val" is supposed to be defined as). I also have the php code which I don't know how to set that up either. I tried to send a request to a local SQL XAMPP database.

AJAX:

```
function callDB() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "js/DBcall.php",
      type: "post",
      data: val,
  dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data.status +':' + data.message);   
            $("#result").addClass('msg_notice');
            $("#result").fadeIn(1500);           
      },
      error:function(){
          $("#result").html('There was an error updating the settings');
          $("#result").addClass('msg_error');
          $("#result").fadeIn(1500);
      }   
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
$serverName = "127.0.0.1\\inventory-manager,3306"; // serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"inventory-manager", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Any help would be so much appreciated!! I really want to learn how to do this, but I can't find any good online resources for doing this using phonegap. They're all really vague. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but at worst it will help other people.

### Cordova and Server

I notice that in your javascript code you do not give an IP address when you call AJAX

```
url: "[NO IP HERE]js/DBcall.php",
```

A cordova application is its own web server and therefore cannot attach remote PHP code without IP. It therefore needs the IP of your server (i.e. your computer) to be able to reach it.

If you are on the same network, you must prefix with your local ip :

```
url: "192.168.1.5/js/DBcall.php",
```

### Val is undefined

You can see : `dataType: 'json'` so in fact, you'r `val` object will be a json string.

You don't give me enough detail, so I'm going to extrapolate a little bit.
Let's say you want to send two variable to the server: cat and dog

You're going to have a code that looks like this:

```
data : JSON.stringify({ cat: MyCatValue, dog: MyDogValue })
```

### Your PHP code is from the 80s.

Sorry to say this but in my opinion the tutorial you went to see must be old enough.

To contact a MySQL database in PHP I advise you to use PDO2 like this :

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'MY_DB_NAME';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO animals ( dogName, catName ) values ( :dogName, :catName )");
    $stmt->bindParam(':dogName', $dogName);
    $stmt->bindParam(':catName', $catName);

    $dogName = 'foo';
    $catName = 'bar';
    $stmt->execute();

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    file_put_contents('error_log.txt', $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

### Be carefull

isn't the best way to do it, you should use a singleton of PDO2 class by example but it's a short code for help you